# How to send text to printer with right to left direction in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I want to print some data in the form using the code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("السيد {0}", lstCustomers.Text), regularFont, Brushes.Black, 30, y);
```

but there are some Arabic text beside English once. And here, If the layout is not set as RightToLeft, the text not appear correctly.

The problem is: In printing, I don't see the property needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `StringFormat` and specify format flag to `DirectionRightToLeft`, So:

```
using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("السيد {0}"), font, brush, location, format);
}
```